# Как в Qt программно записать какой-нибудь текст в QLineEdit

Tags: qt5

В QLineEdit планируется вводить фамилии. Как сделать, чтобы они автоматически дописывались в зависимости от того какие первые буквы были введены. Т.е. получить в QLineEdit заранее заготовленный текст. И, как более сложный вариант, организовать выпадающий список, если введенные первые буквы будут совпадать с несколькими фамилиями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для автодополнения существует класс `QCompleter`:

```
QStringList list;
list << "Some" << "Text" << "To" << "Complete";    
QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(list,this);
ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

Поведение интерфейса настраивается с помощью `setCompletionMode`

> И, как более сложный вариант, организовать выпадающий список, если введенные первые буквы будут совпадать с несколькими фамилиями.

Этому поведению соответствует режим по умолчанию `QCompleter::PopupCompletion`

Answer (score 1):

Заменить `QLineEdit` на `QComboBox`. У последнего заполнить словарь.

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос. В QComboBox есть возможность вписать текст не из словаря?

Comment: @yurasja да, такая возможность есть.